# delete CVS tag that was created earlier

Tags: eclipse, cvs

Please let me know how to delete a CVS tag which was already created from eclipse.

If the tag is removed, can a new tag be created with same name?

Answer (score 13):

I don't think there's a way from Eclipse...you'll have to go to the command line and run:

```
cvs tag -d <tag> <file/directory>
```

or if the tagged files are no longer on your system:

```
cvs rtag -d <tag> <location_in_repository>
```

Comment: Maybe obvious, but first set your `CVSROOT`.  Then `cd` to the folder where you checked out the project.  Hopefully you have cvs  installed... ;)  This answer worked for me too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to replace the tagged code with the new one, you can simply tag the current code with the same tag name of the existing tag, but be sure to check the option "move tag if already exists".

Answer (score 0):

So you actually can do this from Eclipse.  You can hit it from a number of ways, 2 places I've seen it are:

1. *Configure Branches and Versions* if you right click on a branch or version in the CVS Repository Exploring view you will see this option
2. *Configure Tags* if you do a compare on a project or file in your Java view you will see this option.

From there there's a section in the middle called *remembered tags for these projects* and next to that is the Remove button that can be clicked after you select the tag in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete your tag and create a new one with the same name.

You can even commit into your tag (you should not do that).

I dont know how to do this with eclipse, I used always Tortoise client.